# My system can't find command, though I can find it manually

Tags: debian, command, path

When I had enter any command (`grub`, `parted`, `gparted`, `fdisk`) my system cannot find it, although it is present on a disk, because the distribution has installed and works.

But when I invoke any command, I get that error that the command is unknown. How can I fix it?

```
root@debian:/# fdisk
bash: fdisk: command not found
```

```
root@debian:/# apt-get install fdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
fdisk is already the newest version (2.38.1-5+b1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
root@debian:/# find / -type f -name fdisk*
/usr/share/man/man8/fdisk.8.gz
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fdisk
/usr/sbin/fdisk
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fdisk.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fdisk.list
```

My distribution is Debian 12.0.0 i386 1:

```
system Linux debian 6.1.0-9-686-pae #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.27-1 (2023-05-08) i686 GNU/Linux
```

and my PATH is now:

```
root@debian:/home/lm# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/opt/bin:/home/lm/usr/sbin:/root/usr/sbin:/root/usr/share/man/man8
```

```
root@debian:/home/lm# fdisk man
bash: fdisk: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm# fdisk
bash: fdisk: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm#
```

after PATH CORRECTION nothing was changed. May be i had added not properly path to /usr/sbin or what? (and still don't work commands :  reboot, shutdown -r, sysctrl reboot)

i can call now with direct path prompt in a command, but it still don't find by the system,EVEN
after i had improved my PATH.
May be i had improperly corrected it?

```
root@debian:/home/lm# /sbin/fdisk
fdisk: bad usage
Try 'fdisk --help' for more information.
root@debian:/home/lm# fdisk
bash: fdisk: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm#
```

Comment: may be there are some utility to improve PATH on Debian?
because of i didn't meet such a problem before, I think, that there must be some utility who include all folders to path while installation continued? 
i think that impossible manually correct all the PATH ?

Comment: Check if you can call `fdisk` with `/sbin/fdisk`

Comment: yes, i can call but even after PATH changed, the just fdisk call didn't works. 
```

Comment: You can add it temporarily to your current session:

`export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`

To make this permanent, add the line `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file | Don't forget to reload your `bashrc` with `. ~/.bashrc `

Comment: thanx, now i understand the reason - i had add not desired pass, there was need /sbin only.
Do you know, why i didn't meet this problem before in a fresh installed system?